# Функция воспроизведения аудио и остановка

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

Есть две кнопки: ***пуск*** и ***пауза***. Как объединить эти две кнопки в одну со сменой иконки?

То есть, нажали на ***пуск*** - `аудио` запущен, а иконка сменилась на ***паузу***. При нажатии на кнопку ещё раз поток останавливается, а иконка опять меняется на ***пуск***?

```html
<audio id='player' src='http://бла-бла-радиопоток.mp3' />
<div style='position:absolute;  top:154px;  left:0px;  z-index:11;     width:104px;     line-height:98px;'>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).play()'><font size='+1'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-play'/></font></button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).pause()'><font size='+1'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-pause'/></font></button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).volume+=0.1'><font size='+2'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-volume-up'/></font></button>
  <button onclick='document.getElementById(&quot;player&quot;).volume=Math.max(document.getElementById(&quot;player&quot;).volume - 0.1, 0)'><font size='+2'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-volume-down'/></font></button>
  <script>
    var myVid = document.getElementById( & #39;player&# 39;);
    myVid.volume = 0.1;
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Что за шутки????  Не надо так делать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let play = document.querySelector('.play');
// создаем объект AUDIO
const audio = new Audio();

// сразу выставляем уровень звука на средний
let volume = .5
audio.volume = volume;

// присваиваем объекту AUDIO трек
audio.src = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/344175395/stream?client_id=LvWovRaJZlWCHql0bISuum8Bd2KX79mb';

// показываем какой уровень выставлен
document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;

// функция для понижения уровня звука 
document.querySelector('.volume-down').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.volume !== 0) {
    volume -= .1;
    // метод .toFixed() нужен для того чтобы убрать 
    // все лшние цифры кроме первой после точки
    audio.volume = volume.toFixed(1);
    document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});
document.querySelector('.volume-up').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.volume !== 1) {
    volume += .1;
    audio.volume = volume.toFixed(1);
    document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});

// функция для полного отключения звука
document.querySelector('.mute').addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.muted = audio.muted == false ? true : false;
})


// функция для запуска и паузы музыки
play.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    play.classList.add('fa-pause');
    play.classList.remove('fa-play');
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    play.classList.remove('fa-pause');
    play.classList.add('fa-play');
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.mute {
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*
.play {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=play);
}

.pause {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=pause);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--кнопка запуска плеера она же и пауза-->
<button class=" play fa fa-play"></button>
<!--кнопка понижения  звук-->
<button class="volume-down">-</button>
<!--кнопка повышение звука-->
<button class="volume-up">+</button>
<!--уровень звука-->
<span class="vol"></span>
<!--кнопка отключения звука-->
<button class="mute">Mute</button>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87687/discussion-on-answer-by-air-----).